# broken apt update due to change of sources.list

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, mqtt

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get 1http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [32.6 kB]      
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]                                                                   
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [330 kB] 
Hit:3 https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/debian stretch InRelease                             
Ign:5 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/raspbian buster InRelease                                  
Get:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]                               
Err:7 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/raspbian buster Release                                   404  Not Found [IP: 54.183.113.236 443] 
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                 
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/raspbian buster Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I was trying to update packages and found that there is an error caused by the Rabbit MQ which I installed earlier.

I still remember that I was following some instruction to modify **sources.list** or **sources.list.d** or maybe other file to add RabbitMQ's url, but I forget where it is.

I opened the /etc/aptsources.list and there isn't the rabbitmq url.

How can I find where and what file is the string **'https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/raspbian buster Release'** located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you have the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list` Or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.erlang.list` and if so move them out.

Then run `sudo apt update`

If I remember correctly, you have a couple of goes at different installers with Erlang...

You can track your previous questions by looking at your profile [here in your case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/113946/franva).

Note the above MAY WELL be wrong as I'm not sure how you got everything installed first and hence the move not delete recommendation.

Comment: Great~! finally my problem is solved, you are correct, there is the file ```/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list``` thanks a lot~!